# How to subset a table of text in R

Tags: r, subset, import-from-csv

I am using R 3.1.3 32-bit on Windows OS, and have a csv file - commas delimited - with 8 columns and 1001 rows (including the header) (the entire dataset is 24000+ rows).

My aim is to pull out all the rows where the "Site" name contains at least one of the words "HOSPITAL", "ROYAL" "TRUST".

```
> datac <- read.csv("data1c.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character"))) 
Error: unexpected ')' in "datac <- read.csv("data1c.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character")))"
```

AND

```
> read.csv("data1c.csv", header = TRUE, col.names = c("ODS","Site","NGrouping", "Address1", "Address2", "Address3", "Address4", "Postcode")
Error in match.arg(numerals) : 'arg' should be one of “allow.loss”, “warn.loss”, “no.loss”
```

AND

```
> subset("data1c.csv", Site=="HOSPITAL")
Error in subset.default("data1c.csv", Site == "HOSPITAL") : object 'Site' not found
```

AND

```
> x <- matrix(rnorm(8008, 1), ncol = 8)
> y <- c(1, seq(8))
> x <- cbind(x, y)

Warning message:
In cbind(x, y) :
   number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

I am very new to this so any help would  be much appreciated.

Comment: You have at least one syntax error for every line. For instance, in the first line you don't need the last `)`. In the second you missed the `c` after the `col.names` argument. In `subset` you pass a `data.frame`, not a file name (do you know the difference?).

Comment: WHat in the world does the last block of code have to do with the earlier ones? Is this homework?  On the second block just look at the list of column names, the code highlighting right here shows you which one is not like the others.

Answer (score 0):

For you first error, you have an extra `)` is the end (three instead of two).

For the second, you forgot to put your list of column names in a vector, so `read.csv` treats it as extra arguments, do:

```
read.csv("data1c.csv", header = TRUE, col.names =c("ODS","Site","NGrouping", "Address1", "Address2", "Address3", "Address4", "Postcode")
```

For the third, the first argument to subset must be a `data.frame` :

```
subset(datac, Site%in%c("HOSPITAL", "ROYAL", "TRUST"))
```

For the warning, `x` has 1001 rows and 8 columns while `y` is a vector of length 9 (`1 + length(seq(8))`) which is exactly what the warning is telling you. So you must either remove one item from `y` or add a column to `x`

Comment: Thank you Math. I tried your code:

> datac <- read.csv("data1c.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character"))

> read.csv("data1c.csv", header = TRUE, col.names =c("ODS","Site","NGrouping", "Address1", "Address2", "Address3", "Address4", "Postcode")

+ subset(datac, Site%in%c("HOSPITAL", "ROYAL", "TRUST")

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"read.csv("data1c.csv", header = TRUE, col.names =c("ODS","Site","NGrouping", "Address1", "Address2", "Address3", "Address4", "Postcode")
subset"

Comment: Please use ` to delimitated your code for clarity. From the error message you have a syntax error. I would say you put everything on the same line which is not how R works, try executing first `read.csv`, then `subset`